# Rails Routing Error w/ key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I made this custom Route 
on my routes.rb

```
get'dashboard_report_m/:date/:branch_id'=>'reports#monthly_and_branch'
```

I'm Getting Routing Error, No route matches [GET] "/dashboard_report_m"
on my rake routes I have this

on rake routes

```
GET /dashboard(.:format)    reports#today_admin
GET /dashboard_report/:date/:branch_id(.:format)    reports#date_and_branch
GET /dashboard_report_m/:date/:branch_id(.:format)  reports#monthly_and_branch
```

all the other routes I made are fine but this one just doesn't seem to work.
I tried removing the keys `':date/:branch_id'`
and it would work just fine.

I have already made similar routes and they all work just fine except for this one.

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm gettting no route error. for this particular route only.

Comment: there's no space between `get` and `'dashboard_report...` - could that be the problem or is that just a typo here?

Comment: actually it does have a space on my code. any I don't think its a typo. because i tried removing the keys and it was able to access my controller and method. I cant seem to make it work with keys on it

Comment: On my rake routes I have this
'GET /dashboard_report_m/:date/:branch_id(.:format) reports#monthly_and_branch'

yet i still get No route matches [GET] "/dashboard_report_m"

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

1. Is there a `ReportsController` with a ​`monthly_and_branch` action?
2. Does the error occur if you visit `/dashboard_report_m/2016-09-20/1234` directly or are you using a path helper?

UPDATE

OK so you are accessing the path `http://localhost:3000/dashboard_report_m/?date=2016-09&branch_id=1` - you are passing the parameters in as query params, this is not how your route is set up. The way you have it now it is expecting `dashboard_report_m/2016-09/1`. You need to either remove the date and branch_id params from your route or change the way you access the URL. I suggest reading the [Rails Routing from the Outside In guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: 1. Yes the controller and method does exist, I have already tried it.
2. I'm using Postman to access the routes. and its being access like this http://localhost:3000/dashboard_report_m/?date=2016-09&branch_id=1

Answer (score 1):

When you access the following route:

```
localhost:3000/dashboard_report_m/?date=2016-09&branch_id=1
```

This is a `GET` request to `'dashboard_report_m'`, with *query parameters*: `params['date'] = '2016-09'` and `params['branch_id'] = '1'`.

What you should instead be doing is accessing this route:

```
localhost:3000/dashboard_report_m/2016-09/1
```

This is a `GET` request to `'dashboard_report_m/:date/:branch_id'` - i.e. using the *bound parameters* of `date` and `branch_id`.

Further reading: Understand the difference between [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) and the [query string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string). This is by no means specific to Rails; it's at the core of how all web applications work.